# Reputation change missing from recent achievements dropdown?

Tags: bug, reputation, achievements-dialog

Take a look at the screenshots below. I have earned some positive reputation today, but it is missing from the recent achievements dropdown. Badges earned do show up there though.

[image: reputation change]
[image: recent achievements dropdown]